# Push Notification in TWA shows an indicator in Chrome Icon instead app icon

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, twa

I am building a Trusted Web Activity based on a Progressive Web App. Mostly everything works just fine, but the moment a web push notification is received by the device, in the android launcher the chrome app gets an indicator (small dot on the icon) instead of the actual TWA. I am using a virtual device from Android Studio (Android API 30) for testing this. I expected the indicator on the app icon instead of the Chrome icon. After clicking on the indicator the dot on the chrome icon disappears.

[Screenshot of Android with indicator on Chrome icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUEVv.png)

The first try was that I built it based on the [svgomg-twa](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa) example and now I tried to create the TWA with bubblewrap explained [here](https://developers.google.com/web/android/trusted-web-activity/quick-start). Both options result in the same behavior like explained before.

I am happy to provide further details, but I am missing the starting point what could be responsable for this indicator behavior. So please just let me know if you need some more information.

I would be very happy if you could give me a starting point to figure this out.

Thanks in advance,
Matthias

Comment: Does the icon of your app have a chrome icon over one corner? If so, you have not installed your PWA, but simply added a shortcut to your website. (just guessing here)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! No, the app is really installed, I built an apk and installed it with `adb install` on my computer and the app icon does not show a chrome icon.

Comment: This looks like a bug. If this is still reproducible, would you mind filing a bug at https://crbug.com/?